# Can't set Content-Type header on HttpResponseMessage headers?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm using the ASP.NET WebApi.  I'm creating a PUT method within one of my controllers, and the code looks like this:

```cs
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int idAssessment, int idCaseStudy, string value) 
{
    var response = Request.CreateResponse();
    
    if (!response.Headers.Contains("Content-Type")) 
        response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain");

    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    
    return response;
}
```

When I PUT to that location with the browser via AJAX, it gives me this Exception:

> Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with
> HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and
> content headers with HttpContent objects.

But isn't `Content-Type` a perfectly valid header for a response?  Why am I getting this exception?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Have a look at the [HttpContentHeaders.ContentType Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httpcontentheaders.contenttype.aspx):

```
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain");
```

---

```
if (response.Content == null)
{
    response.Content = new StringContent("");
    // The media type for the StringContent created defaults to text/plain.
}
```

Comment: What if the response has no content (so `.Content` is null)?  I'm wanting to set the Content-Type header even though there's no content, otherwise Firefox complains with a "no element found" error.

Comment: You could also try setting `response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NoContent` instead of adding the Content-Type header field.

Comment: Cool, the dummy `response.Content = new StringContent("");` worked.  I am still left wondering why `response.Headers` even exists, though.

Comment: For the headers that are not `Content`-related.

Comment: Well then it's a misleading Exception message.  It's not that Content- stuff doesn't belong in an HTTP response, it's that those headers are treated specially by WebApi.

Comment: Yes; WebApi separates the header fields into response header and content header.

Comment: This is just ridiculous. I'm so glad WebApi is done. Long live MVC.

Comment: There is a problem with `StringContent`: some problematic headers are sent: `Content-Type` and `Content-Language`.

Comment: in Microsoft tradition, the API is idiotic. What may be useful to uses is someway of determining if the header they have qualifies as a content header... Oh `KnownHeaders` exists you say? Oh it is `internal`? Fuck you Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

Something is missing in ASP Web API: the `EmptyContent` type. It will allow sending an empty body while still allowing all content-specific headers.

Put the following class somewhere in your code :

```
public class EmptyContent : HttpContent
{
    protected override Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    protected override bool TryComputeLength(out long length)
    {
        length = 0L;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then use it as you wish. You now have a content object for your extra headers.

```
response.Content = new EmptyContent();
response.Content.Headers.LastModified = file.DateUpdatedUtc;
```

Why use `EmptyContent` instead of `new StringContent(string.Empty)`?

- [`StringContent`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/ByteArrayContent.cs) is a heavy class that executes lots of codes (because it inherits [`ByteArrayContent`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/ByteArrayContent.cs))

  - so let's save a few nanoseconds
- `StringContent` will add an extra useless/problematic header: `Content-Type: plain/text; charset=...`

  - so let's save a few network bytes