# Content type in HTTP call

Tags: c#, .net, rest, httpresponse, http-put

My HTTP Put call response is printed by the following code.

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsync("https://restapi.surveygizmo.com/v4/survey/2692209/surveypage/3/surveyquestion?", inputMessage.Content);

string returnString = response.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(returnString);
Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
```

I want to print the content type information to be printed on console or some other format. Basically i want to see the content type in c#. How do i do that?

Comment: Do you look for the content type or content response ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [HttpContent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpcontent.aspx) and read the buffer.

> A base class representing an HTTP entity body and content headers.

```
using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
{
    // ... Read the string.
    string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    // ... Display the result.
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

Comment: Got the answer which i wanted, but i get this exception later An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: I hope you're using `result` variable and not reruning the `content.ReadAsStringAsync()`.

Comment: Yes i am using the result variable. The program runs fine and i get the answer butt I get exception after that An unhandled exception of type 'System.AggregateException' at this placce i think  RunQuestions().Wait();

Comment: Looks like the initial question is satisfied and you should open a new question. Good luck :)

Answer (score 2):

By using the Content.Headers.ContentType information stored in the response ([Can't set Content-Type header on HttpResponseMessage headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377957/cant-set-content-type-header-on-httpresponsemessage-headers)).

E.g., to write the Console-Type to console, you would do the following:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PutAsync("https://restapi.surveygizmo.com/v4/survey/2692209/surveypage/3/surveyquestion?", inputMessage.Content);

Console.WriteLine(response.Content.Headers.ContentType);
```