# Trying to get the Content-Type header of the response causes an exception with xUnit

Tags: asp.net-core, http, http-headers, xunit, response-headers

For some reason the last assert of this xUnit test throws an exception:     `System.InvalidOperationException : Misused header name, 'Content-Type'. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.`

```
[Fact]
public async Task MapGet_Should_Return_the_Correct_Student_When_They_Exist_With_200OK()
{
    //Arrange
    await using var application = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>();
    using HttpClient? client = application.CreateClient();

    //Act
    await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/student/s1", new Student("X", "Y", "Z"));  

    HttpResponseMessage? result = await client.GetAsync("/student/s1");

    string? contentAsString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var contentAsStudentObject =
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Student>(contentAsString);

    //Assert
    Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, result.StatusCode);

    Assert.NotNull(contentAsStudentObject);

    Assert.Equal("X", contentAsStudentObject.FirstName);
    Assert.Equal("Y", contentAsStudentObject.LastName);
    Assert.Equal("Z", contentAsStudentObject.FavouriteSubject);

    Assert.Equal("application/json; charset=utf-8", result.Headers.GetValues("Content-Type").First());
}
```

I don't understand why it is happening. That's exactly what I am doing. I am using a response header with an HttpResponseMessage object (`result`, namely).

I am not sure that there is some point in actually testing that exact thing as it's something the framework does for us automatically. Which middleware is actually responsible for that (setting the `Content-Type` of the response)? Still I don't understand why the exception is happening, so that's why I posted the question and think it holds.

The response headers for the request:
[image]

The body (of the response) is:

```
{
    "firstName": "x",
    "lastName": "y",
    "favouriteSubject": "z"
}
```

Can someone spot what's happening? Thank you!

**P.P. I've just found that the code works with**

```
Assert.Equal("application/json; charset=utf-8", result.Content.Headers.GetValues("Content-Type").First());
```

Why can't we access it the other way, though?

Answer (score 0):

You could check the document related with [HttpRequestHeaderCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.headers.httprequestheadercollection?view=winrt-19041#properties),

[HttpResponseHeaderCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.headers.httpresponseheadercollection?view=winrt-22621#properties),(Provides a collection of the HTTP headers associated with an HTTP response.)

[HttpContentHeaderCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.headers.httpcontentheadercollection?view=winrt-22621#properties)(Provides a collection of the HTTP headers associated with content on an HTTP request or response.)

[image]

The headers mentioned in the document,such as  `Content-Length`,`Content-type`,`Content-Language` (related with request/response body distinguish with headers for request/response itself) could only be added into/get from `HttpContentHeaderCollection`,once you try add them into /get them from`HttpRequestHeaderCollection`/`HttpResponseHeaderCollection`,the error would occour and metion you misused the header (If you try  `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-type",....)`you would also get the same error)

Some related issue :

[Can't set Content-Type header on HttpResponseMessage headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377957/cant-set-content-type-header-on-httpresponsemessage-headers)